# RMI : RemoteAccountService extends Remote

Tags: java, spring

I have a weird question, I was reading the Spring Integration Documentation, under "[19. Remoting and web services using Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html)" section, there is an interface, but it is not used anywhere.  Why does the documentation talk about this interface at all?

```
public interface RemoteAccountService extends Remote {
    public void insertAccount(Account account) throws RemoteException;
    public List<Account> getAccounts(String name) throws RemoteException;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It gets implemented for the JAX-RPC wrapper class in section [19.5.1](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html). Pasting the first few lines of section [19.5.1](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html) discussion below:-

```
/**
 * JAX-RPC compliant RemoteAccountService implementation that simply delegates
 * to the AccountService implementation in the root web application context.
 *
 * This wrapper class is necessary because JAX-RPC requires working with dedicated
 * endpoint classes. If an existing service needs to be exported, a wrapper that
 * extends ServletEndpointSupport for simple application context access is
 * the simplest JAX-RPC compliant way.
 *
 * This is the class registered with the server-side JAX-RPC implementation.
 * In the case of Axis, this happens in "server-config.wsdd" respectively via
 * deployment calls. The web service engine manages the lifecycle of instances
 * of this class: A Spring application context can just be accessed here.
 */import org.springframework.remoting.jaxrpc.ServletEndpointSupport;

public class AccountServiceEndpoint extends ServletEndpointSupport implements RemoteAccountService {
```